# js event handler does not intercept form submission (Mixed Active Content)

Tags: javascript, forms, firefox, event-handling

-- EDIT: This turns out not to be a js issue but a "Mixed Active Content" issue in Firefox 24.0. --

Locally, an event handler correctly intercepts a form submission; however, on Heroku, the application instead issues an HTTP request and the appropriate Javascript function is never called.

My webpage has the following Javascript:

```
<script id="infrastructure-cxn" type="application/javascript">
  $(function () {

    // [additional code ... ]

    $("#message-form").submit(function (event) {
      event.preventDefault();

      var msg = $("#msg-input").val();
      var msgObject = { text: msg };
      server.publish(channel, msgObject);
    });

  });
</script>
```

My webpage has the following form:

```
<form id="message-form" accept-charset="UTF-8">
  <!-- [additional code ...] -->
  <div class="field">
    <input
      id="msg-input"
      type="text"
      placeholder="Enter message..." />
  </div>
  <input
    class="btn btn-xs btn-primary"
    type="submit"
    value="Send" />
</form>
```

Could anyone offer any suggestions as to how I can fix my application so that in production it doesn't issue either GET or POST requests but instead calls the anonymous function in my event handler?

Comment: Have you attempted to place a breakpoint inside the event handler to ensure it is being called properly? At first pass your code appears to be correct - I don't see why it would behave differently when run from the server

Comment: What does your console have to say? There may be other errors on the page that are preventing this code from being executed.

Comment: Thanks, pdoherty926. My console indicated that Firefox 24 didn't load from my secondary server because of mixed active content.